# Complex After save association in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, callback, ruby-on-rails-3.2, after-save

Theory :- after create of a record in `customer bill`, i am sending two sets of data two different models. one set of data is sent to `ledger` and one set of data is sent to `ledger_line_item`. the complexity is that after sending of data i want the `ledger_id` to be stored in `ledger_line_item`. the code is as follows

code :-

```
class CustomerBill < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_create :creating_ledger_line_items, :creating_ledger_items

  def creating_ledger_items
    CustomerLedger.create(:customer_id =>self.customer_id,/*rest of attributes*/)
  end

  def creating_ledger_line_items
    CustomerLedgerLineItem.create(:customer_id =>self.customer_id,/*rest of attributes*/)
  end
end
```

in ledger i have written

```
class CustomerLedger < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_save :update_record_line_items

  def update_record_line_items
    a = CustomerLedgerLineItem.find_by_customer_id(self.customer_id)
    a.update_attributes(:customer_ledger_id => self.id)
  end
end
```

the above code works fine without error but the `ledger_id` is not been posted in `ledger_line_items`. i am not able to determine why this error is happening? is there any other way i can achieve my goal of posting `ledger_id` in `ledger_line_items` after a bill is created? 
Guidance Required. Thanking you in advance.

Comment: the way i see it is you're manually creating the items given a list of attributes.  You can achieve what you want by looking at `accepts_nested_attributes_for` which will simplify your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your models something as follows.:

I am assuming you have `Customer Model`.

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :customer_ledger
  has_many :customer_ledger_line_items, :through => :customer_ledger   
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :customer_ledger

end

class CustomerLedger < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :customer_ledger_line_items
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :customer_ledger_line_items
end

class CustomerBill < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
  after_create :creating_ledger_items, :creating_ledger_line_items

  def creating_ledger_line_items
   cl = self.customer.customer_ledger.build(your_attributes)
   cl.save!
  end

  def creating_ledger_items
    cli = self.customer.customer_ledger.customer_ledger_items.build(your_attributes)
    cli.save!     
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to create the models on an *after_create* hook, I'll explain what's the problem.

When you create a model in rails, and you have hooks like *after_create*, *before_update*, etc. all the updates happens in a Transaction, so if any of them throws an exception, nothing is updated.

In this case, within a Transaction, you are trying to get the ID of a CustomerLedger that doesn't exists yet, because since everything is within a Transaction, the record is not saved to the database until the transaction is executed, and thats the reason that on CustomerLedger#update_record_line_items, self.id is always nil.

Using the nested attributes proposed by codeit is probably the best solution to your problem, but if you feel that nested attributes its an advance topic, you can do something like:

```
class CustomerBill < ActiveRecord::Base

  after_create :created_leder_data

  def create_ledger_data
    customer_ledger = CustomerLedger.build(customer_id: self.customer_id, # Rest of attributes)
    customer_ledger.customer_ledger_line_items.build(customer_id: self.customer_id, # Rest of attributes)
    customer_ledger.save!
  end
end
```